# How to change the value of format specifier at runtime?

Tags: c++, c, scanf, format-specifiers

I am using **sscanf** in my project to copy strings from source buffer to target buffer.
For example:

```
char* target;
target = (char*)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
char* source = "Hello World";
sscanf(source, "%[^\t\n]", target); // trying to copy "Hello World" into target.
printf("%s\n", target);//this will print "Hello World".
```

But this way of coding style is not accepted. What my manager want me to do is something like:

```
sscanf(source, "%11[^\t\n]", target); // NOTE: I've written "%11". here, 11 == length of hello world.
```

That means, he want me to provide format specifiers as well. (%11 in this case).

But, the problem is that source can be of varying length and I don't know how to write the correct format specifier for every varying length string.

Comment: have you considered strtok() instead?

Comment: The control string is just a string. You can count the number of characters and then assemble an appropriate control string.

Comment: [Please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169). Also, don't use `sizeof (char)`, it's always 1 and just adds confusion.

Comment: I don't know much about C. What difference does adding the size of the string make?

Comment: @Neil Kirk If I _grok_ your comment: adding "11" to form "%11[^\t\n]" limits the maximum number of `char` put in `target` as `source` could have been much bigger than the destination's capacity.

Comment: @chux Thanks. If I understand this problem correctly, what is the point of working out the size of the string and then using that limit again?

Comment: @Neil Kirk OP's nicely terse post prevented me from divining that detail as to why `source` size is used twice.  `target = strdup(source)` looks good (expect it does not filter out \t\n.  It would seem that target successfully allocated with size of strlen(source)+1 would allow `sscanf(source, "%[^\t\n]", target)` to _always_ work.  Maybe OP's manger wants 2 safety nets?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<strike>Use:</strike>

```
sscanf(source, "%*[^\t\n]", maxlen, target)
```

where maxlen is the size you want to read.

There appears to be no trivial way to make a format string for `sscanf` (or any of it's siblings) take an arbitrary max length of the input string. The suggestion was based on `printf` being orthogonal to `scanf`, which turns out to not be the case.

You may find you have better luck using `strtok` and either `strncpy` or `strdup` to copy the token.

However, since it's tagged C++, why not use:

```
std::stringstream ss(source);  
std::string target;
getline(ss, target, "\t");
```

Comment: I have used this line --->  scanf(source, "%*[^\t\n]", maxlen, target);  but its giving me garbage value.

Comment: Yeah, it's incorrect - `scanf()` isn't orthogonal to `printf` in this aspect. It means "skip input", not "take input value to be length". I don't actually think there is a C way [aside from using something like `sprintf` to generate a string from it]. I will edit my answer to that effect...

Comment: I think you mean "analogous" instead of "orthogonal"

Comment: @pelletjl: No, I'm using orthogonal in the computer science meaning: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonality#Computer_science

Answer (score 0):

For copying string use `strcpy()`. It does not allocate space, so you have to provide the second buffer too. There's also `strncpy()` which will not copy more than specified characters.

If you want to make a copy of a string in one go you can use `strdup()`, just don't forget to free the memory afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

First, use strcpy() for this.

Second, the format specifier is just a string, so just use sprintf() to make it after taking strlen() of the string you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use `target = strdup(source)` or if still obliged to use `sscanf()`:

*Dynamically* create the format.

```
const char* source = "Hello World";
size_t n = 10;  // See note below
char* target;
target = (char*) malloc(n);  // (char *) is needed for C++, but not C
char format[1+20+5+1];
sprintf(format, "%%" "%zu" "[^\t\n]", n - 1);
sscanf(source, format, target); // trying to copy "Hello World" into target.
printf("%s\n", source);//this will print "Hello World".
printf("%s\n", target);//this will print "Hello Wor".
```

---

You would likely want `n = strlen(source) + 1`, but the above illustrates how a dynamically created format specifier for `scanf()` prevents buffer overrun in `target`.

Comment: Last line is wrong. `scanf`'s `%s` stops reading at the first whitespace.

Comment: A pedantic solution would handle `n == 1` as a special case as `"%0[^\t\n]"` is UB.